# How to create Parent-child transition in which list item lifts out and become details screen

Tags: android

How to create Parent-child transition in which list item lifts out and become details screen like shown in below picture:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using sharedElementTransitions in android, you can have two fragments, master and detailFragment. This animation will be applied when you replace the fragment. For reference check out this link

https://medium.com/@bherbst/fragment-transitions-with-shared-elements-7c7d71d31cbb

Comment: this is not what i wanted.

Comment: Obviously this is not the exact code, hence I said you can take reference from here not the exact code. It is easy to modify this code and achieve what you want using elevation and shape transition